# CSST gas line termination OK?

Tags: plumbing, gas, csst

To me the termination of this CSST gas line to my gas stove looks a bit suspect. Is this installation ok? The yellow jacket on the line is peeled back a bit, about an inch and a half from the fitting. It's been working fine for years, to be clear. Does the jacket split matter?[image: Picture of gas line termination]

Answer (score 1):

This is bad. The protective jacket has pulled away from the flange nut and has probably exposed the CSST tubing at the bottom. The retainer ring is holding the tubing in place but this needs to be fixed. That bend looks excessive. Call your gas company. They might come out and fix it at no charge

Comment: Fix at no charge? I'd expect them to tag it, turn off the gas and tell you to call a licensed plumber.